# how to use where clause after a group by result in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table,

```
    mysql> select username,authdate from radpostauth;
+------------+---------------------+
| username   | authdate            |
+------------+---------------------+
| timetest   | 2013-05-21 22:44:46 |
| timetest   | 2013-05-21 23:54:20 |
| coconeja   | 2013-05-22 00:01:42 |
| coconeja   | 2013-05-22 00:06:35 |
| coconeja   | 2013-05-25 22:35:34 |
| timetest   | 2013-05-25 23:04:54 |
| distom11   | 2013-05-25 23:10:47 |
| distom11   | 2013-05-25 23:16:42 |
| test       | 2013-05-25 23:45:16 |
| pepe       | 2013-05-26 00:07:00 |
| doce       | 2013-05-26 00:46:48 |
| 6096753968 | 2013-05-26 01:42:30 |
| 2269664468 | 2013-05-26 01:43:57 |
| 2076877624 | 2013-05-26 02:01:53 |
| 4446830988 | 2013-05-26 02:02:28 |
| 2076877624 | 2013-05-26 02:08:53 |
| 3906187975 | 2013-05-26 22:00:30 |
| 3906187975 | 2013-05-26 22:21:44 |
| kk         | 2013-05-26 22:32:20 |
| kk         | 2013-05-26 22:44:19 |
| 160059817  | 2013-05-27 00:53:56 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:32:00 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:37:53 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:38:01 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:38:02 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:38:03 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:38:39 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:38:40 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:38:41 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:44:40 |
```

I want to find the 'usernames' who first access was in the last 12 hours.

I know how to get the first time each user have been logged with the following query

```
    mysql> select username,min(authdate) from radpostauth group by username;
+------------+---------------------+
| username   | min(authdate)       |
+------------+---------------------+
| 160059817  | 2013-05-27 00:53:56 |
| 2076877624 | 2013-05-26 02:01:53 |
| 2269664468 | 2013-05-26 01:43:57 |
| 3906187975 | 2013-05-26 22:00:30 |
| 4446830988 | 2013-05-26 02:02:28 |
| 6096753968 | 2013-05-26 01:42:30 |
| coconeja   | 2013-05-22 00:01:42 |
| distom11   | 2013-05-25 23:10:47 |
| doce       | 2013-05-26 00:46:48 |
| kk         | 2013-05-26 22:32:20 |
| pepe       | 2013-05-26 00:07:00 |
| test       | 2013-05-25 23:45:16 |
| timetest   | 2013-05-21 22:44:46 |
| yibced9    | 2013-05-27 13:32:00 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

so now I am triying to get those usernames doing this:

```
select *
from radpostauth
where (
    select username,min(authdate)
    from radpostauth group by username
    ) > timediff( now(),maketime(12,0,0,) );
```

but obviouly it doesn't work...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select username, min(authdate) 
from radpostauth 
group by username
having min(authdate) > NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
```

In SQL, WHERE restricts rows, but HAVING restricts groups.

Comment: more like where operates at the row level while scanning the table, and having operates at the result set level, after all aggregate functions have their results computed.

Answer (score 2):

The perfect answer is Bill's here but for exhaustivity sake David's try is worth correcting:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT username, MIN(authdate) as min_authdate
    FROM radpostauth
    GROUP BY username
) T
WHERE min_authdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR;
```